# XHMTL 1.0 Youtube Video

Tags: xhtml, xhtml-1.0-strict

I've gotten the following code :

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="width:420px; height:240px;" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/zOETaUx3c4o?color2=FBE9EC&amp;version=3">
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/zOETaUx3c4o?color2=FBE9EC&amp;version=3" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
        </object><div style="font-size: 0.8em"><a href="http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/youtube_xhtml/"></a></div>
```

It currently works on Google Chrome and the video does play. However, when doing validation I am being given an error and I can't seem to resolve the issue. Does anyone have any idea why I'm receiving such an error :

Line 92, Column 152: document type does not allow element "object" here; missing one of "p", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "div", "address", "fieldset", "ins", "del" start-tag
…40px;" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/zOETaUx3c4o?color2=FBE9EC&version=3">

Thanks

Comment: You can’t have `object` as a direct child of `body` in XHTML Strict – and the error message already tells you what kind of elements you could try and wrap around it …

Comment: Sorry...new to XHTML... So do I remove object or just add additional elements that are allowed as the primary one?

Comment: Well removing the `object` will not result in much video embedding, don’t you think …?

Comment: Why do you need XHTML 1.0 Strict? I mean, not that I'm opposed to the use of XHTML, but it has very specific rules that have no basis in reality, and you can just use a HTML5 file and be done with it. (HTML5 does not have this silly rule that `body` or `form` or `blockquote` can't contain phrasing content.)